# What is the easiest way to figure out who wrote/edited this line of code?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, cvs

This obviously requires the source file to be under source control. I would ideally like a tool which works under the IDE (Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc) - but an external tool would be nice, too. Obviously, it is possible manually go through previous versions of the file, and compare the various versions, but I am looking for a way to be able to see quickly who is responsible for a code section.

I am using CVS, but the tool should ideally work with different source control systems.

Comment: Ah, and here then is the root of all version control antagonists. Basic accountability. :-o

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That looks like the [blame function](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html), supported in [eclipse with CVS](http://stuvel.eu/archive/42/blame-support-in-eclipse), or with [Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223657/svn-blame-in-eclipse) (also in eclipse)

As you mention, the eclipse-name for that feature is [**Show Annotations**](http://henke.ws/post.cfm/CFEclipse---Eclipse---Show-Annotations).

[image: Eclipse Show-Annotations]

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for. This feature also synchronises with the "History" view, making it easy to check out details regarding the related check-in.

Answer (score 7):

You don't mention wich source control are you using.

If you're using Subversion, you can take a look at:

```
svn blame
```

:)

Comment: He didn't in his initial post. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio .NET with TFS.

The function is "Annotate" and works pretty much the same with Blame.

(personally I refer to these as the team's witch hunt tool).

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad/open. Somehow, it is a good idea, it can be used as reference...

At work, I use Perforce with its graphical interface. The Time-lapse view allows to see the file with, for each line, the revision version in which it has been changed, and details (who submitted the change, when, etc.). And you can move a slider to see previous versions.
There is a command line version: `p4 annotate`.

I am starting to use Mercurial so I looked at it. [Version control systems comparison](http://www.versioncontrolblog.com/comparison/) (good site, I just discovered it) shows that the command is `hg annotate`.

Comment: I found that TortoiseHg (Mercurial client) also includes this feature (Annotate Files)

Answer (score 1):

In AccuRev this is even smarter with the annotate + "version slider" function, which will give you the option to browse through the annotated version of the file in history:

(Not only who changed what on the latest revision, but also on *all* revisions)

[image: Accurev Version Slider]
<sub>(source: [accurev.com](http://www.accurev.com/images/screenshots/4.6/annotate.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In many version control systems including [CVS](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS--Concurrent%20Versions%20System%20v1.12.12.1:%20Guide%20to%20CVS%20commands#SEC134), [Perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367703/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-figure-out-who-wrote-edited-this-line-of-code/368661#368661), [AccuRev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367703/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-figure-out-who-wrote-edited-this-line-of-code/410958#410958), [Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367703/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-figure-out-who-wrote-edited-this-line-of-code/368661#368661), and [Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367703/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-figure-out-who-wrote-edited-this-line-of-code/367749#367749), the command is **`annotate`**.

In [Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367703/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-figure-out-who-wrote-edited-this-line-of-code/367710#367710) and [RCS](http://blame.sourceforge.net/), the command is **`blame`**.

For example, with CVS:

```
cvs annotate foo.cc > foo_changes.txt
```

will create `foo_changes.txt`, which lists the revision number and username associated with the most recent change for each line in the current version of `foo.cc`.  Using different options will give you the same info for previous versions or tagged versions of the file.

I needed this question answered too, but it didn't jump out at me right away when reading the answers already posted, so hopefully this summary should help.

Answer (score 0):

For perforce plugin in Eclipse annotate is not showing up in the context menu.
So I need to use: `p4 annotate my-file` and then using Eclipse browse the history.