# How to find the authors of a method via SVN / Subclipse?

Tags: svn, search, find, subclipse, author

I look at a method in some Java class. I want to know who worked on this method. Is there an easy way to get that information from Subclipse or SVN?

And more general, how do I see who wrote / edited which code or which line of code in a simple view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Blame option in svn.. Rightclick the file Svn->Blame. This is may be diffrent from client to client.

Comment: Here is an description if how to use it via Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223657/svn-blame-in-eclipse