# eclipse blame feature

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Could you advise me some svn plugin for eclipse that visualizes changes made to file? I know there is built-in feature in Text Editors - Quick diff, but it shows differences in overview ruler and I want to see changes as a highlighted lines.

**UPD**: Why do I need it. I often change existing code for some reason. That changes does not have to be committed, so before commit I am reverting them. To do it I run tortoise svn and see which changes are necessary and which are not. That is a bit cumbersome every time switching from tortoise svn to eclipse and back. But if I could see changes right in java editor that would be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found How I can do it. There is blame feature which annotates file with revision where last change was made. And for new lines that annotation is empty. Just what I wanted!

Comment: Maybe also useful for others that did not know how to enable the "blame" feature in Eclipse: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223657/svn-blame-in-eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Compare with some revision to see changes - under "team"

Comment: I could see changes using tortoise svn. What I want is to see highlighted changed lines right in Java editor. Even if I would see that changes in eclipse but in other window that has a small difference from viewing changes in tortoise svn. I have updated question with explanation why I do need it.