# eclipse check in by line when using perforce (like how intelliJ does it)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, perforce

so this is a question i'm struggling to google (i don't know the terms) - i'm sure there is an answer out there  somewhere.

In intelliJ i can press some button (seen my coworkers do it) to see who checked in which lines of code in a file. It is pretty nifty stuff.

Does eclipse let me do that when coupled with perforce? If so, how can i do that?

UPDATE:
And now i see that this is a VC-specific feature, let me expand the question to include the use of perforce.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Eclipse, but with the P4V tool you can use 'Time Lapse View'. It's very powerful and easy to use, and will help you understand who changed which line in complete detail.

See: http://www.perforce.com/resources/tutorials/time-lapse-view

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion vocabulary, this is called a "blame" (or "annotate", this is supported in the Subversive plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/224221/500478

Answer (score 0):

The P4Eclipse plugin has a native blame tool available from the Team menu.